# Saving glut draw as PNG/BMP/JPG

Tags: c, image, save, glut

I'm creating a simple graphic editor by C/glut. So I just wonder how can I save my draws as PNG, BMP etc. I tried png.h but didn't work for me. I didn't get any errors but it did not save anything.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you provide the code of what you've already tried ?

Comment: Did you take a look to this related post [GLUT screen capture in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090892/glut-screen-capture-in-c) ?

Comment: @LudaOtaku
I tried this code and I got undefined reference to error.
Here's link : [link](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html)

I couldn't find other code which didn't work.

J.Piquard;

Yes, but I don't know what can I do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily save bmp images from your app using libsoil.

http://lonesock.net/soil.html

For example, I used:

```
    int save_result = SOIL_save_screenshot(
        filename,
        SOIL_SAVE_TYPE_BMP,
        0,0,
        width, height
    );
```

If you are a debian user, there is a package named `libsoil-dev`. It should be available in Ubuntu too.